# UITextView textViewDidChange-fetch data from backend like UISearch

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, parse-platform

I call an `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` delegate and inside it the code fetches data from my parse.com backend. But 99/100 attempts i get an empty array,in rare cases it gives back the exact data and I list it out in tableview.Any best way to redefine my code? or use any other delegate ?

```
  - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView

    {

  [searchAskerArray removeAllObjects];

    [searchResultArray removeAllObjects];
    NSString *inComingText = _txtQuestion.text;
    if(![inComingText isEqualToString:@" "] && inComingText.length>4 && [[inComingText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count]>0)
    {
            PFQuery *searchQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
            _txtQuestion.text = inComingText;
            [searchQuery includeKey:@"user"];

        [searchQuery whereKey:@"question" containsString:_txtQuestion.text];

    [searchQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *quesArray, NSError *error)
     {

         for (int i = 0; i <quesArray.count; i++)
         {
             NSString *ques  = [quesArray[i] objectForKey:@"question"];
             PFUser *asker = [quesArray[i] objectForKey:@"user"];
             [searchResultArray addObject:ques];
             [searchAskerArray addObject:asker.username];
         }
         if (searchResultArray!=nil && searchAskerArray.count >0)
         {
             finalQuesArray = searchResultArray;
             finalAskerArray = searchAskerArray;
             [_similarTable reloadData];

         }
     }];
}}
```

When the user types fast this delegate takes many event fires at once.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

as search query run in background, have you waited few time to finish the block, so that the response could be seen by placing a breakpoint or using NSLog.

Comment: or how will I redefine the code to reload the table view once the fetching has been done?

Comment: You can have a search button, when pressed, start fetching data from parse.com, you can show an UIActivityIndicator to block UI until the searched results loads in the tableview.

Comment: i want like a search bar concept  so your suggestion goes out of context ! Query for results as soon as user starts typing !

Comment: I got it, but the instant results can be shown from local database, but if you have to fetch data from the server, there will be delay to fetch it. So, there should be work around like i suggested. Anyhow, good luck with solution dear :)